# Import from Shopify

Tags: shopify, virtocommerce

Do you plan to release a new version of this module? I am trying to use, but there is something wrong. Maybe am I missing something?
My VirtoCommerce Core version is 2.4 and the module have Core 2.3 version dependency. After a sucessfull installation, the admin does not load properly.
If I remove the module from Platform/Modules folder, the admin load correctly again.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJpmS.jpg

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this perhaps should be addressed to some devs out there, in a project mailing list.

Comment: this question is in virtocommerce and shopify channels and is directly related to those, why is it off topic and whats wrong with asking support questions for open source projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the module is now updated but haven't made it to the app store yet. Here is the link to the new version: Direct link to 2.4 version
http://virtocommerce.blob.core.windows.net/catalog/Altsoft.ShopifyImport_2.4.0.zip